# How to change the font of Axis label in Pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I have a custom font, I am able to set this font in title of the graph, I need help in setting the axis label font.(left, bottom axis labels)

I am able to set the font to the title of the graph like this

```
    graphWidget = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
    graph = graphWidget.getPlotItem()
    graph.titleLabel.item.setFont(font)
```

I would like to know if there's any similar way to set the font for axis labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set custom `QFont` to axis label, you have to `setFont` for `label` of each `axis`.

Here is a short example, which changes font family to `Times` for title, bottom and left axis.

```
import sys

import pyqtgraph
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Define your font
my_font = QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold)

graphWidget = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
graphWidget.setTitle("My plot")

# Set label for both axes
graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', "My x axis label")
graphWidget.setLabel('left', "My y axis label")

# Set your custom font for both axes
graphWidget.getAxis("bottom").label.setFont(my_font)
graphWidget.getAxis("left").label.setFont(my_font)

graph = graphWidget.getPlotItem()
# Set font for plot title
graph.titleLabel.item.setFont(my_font)

graphWidget.show()
app.exec()
```